# Fetch dynamically generate input elements and pass it to PHP variables

Tags: php

I have the following HTML generated dynamically depending on the mysql Table column names.

```
<form method="GET" action="test.php"> 
<input type="text" placeholder="size" name="size" class="form-control">
<input type="text" placeholder="weight" name="weight" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Now I need to fetch these values and pass it to PHP variables.

I cannot manually assign them as these two inputs are dynamically generated. In future there might appear three inputs based on column names.

Comment: `pass it to PHP variables`? Do you want to store it in dynamic PHP variables or pass it to an array?

Answer (score 0):

Get them by `$var = (isset($_GET)) ? $_GET : '';` or set an array() if none just to make the $var consistent.

If there is even 1 query, or more, it'd be in a form of an array. Like so:

```
Array ( [q] => hello-world )
```

From a url with `?q=hello=world`